# DS9808 rules single barcode

Tags: barcode-scanner, motorola, handheld

The company I work for replaced some handheld scanners recently and need them to have the same functionality as some older ones.  We used to use InterMec-EasySet to create barcodes that performed the following actions.

1. Scan one of 20 barcodes (made in easySet) that contain an address
2. Scan MANY MANY tracking barcodes on packages

Result: After scanning the address barcode the scanner would set its current rule to say "append [tab] "." [tab]' and [Address] to ALL scans from now on.  So that all the scans would fill in the package info and then the destination address in the next field of their DB program.  This would continue until another address is scanned, then it would scrap its rule and make a new one with a different address.

Now we have a Motorola (Symbol) DS9808

It has rule programming but not enough memory to store 20+ addresses.  I can create a series of barcodes to scan one after another to set the rule I want using the [Programming Manual](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=72e-69680&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.symbol.com%2Fmanuals%2F6968003a.pdf&ei=QpM4UZ3zNuvy0wHu1IDIAg&usg=AFQjCNF086EEb-Y5twDMUKXPN5IQJy5JcA&bvm=bv.43287494,d.dmQ%22) However with the amount of traffic this thing will see it would be a huge waste of time.

QUESTION: Sorry it took so long to get to the real question.  Does anyone know how to decode the barcodes in the [Programming Manual](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=72e-69680&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.symbol.com%2Fmanuals%2F6968003a.pdf&ei=QpM4UZ3zNuvy0wHu1IDIAg&usg=AFQjCNF086EEb-Y5twDMUKXPN5IQJy5JcA&bvm=bv.43287494,d.dmQ%22) so that I can create 1 barcode that erases all rules, then sets the default rule to be [data scanned] [tab] "." [tab] [FIXED ADDRESS]

Do not hesitate to ask for clarification if any of this is not clear.

Thank you

Comment: Is your "address" is less than 5 characters? Looks like ADF only supports 8 characters, less 3 for `[tab].[tab]` and suffixes are limited to 4 numeric characters. Can you decode the command barcodes using a smartphone and zxing?

Comment: I decoded one and it gave me 80, and when I created an 80 barcode it only scanned in 80, even though they appear the same to me.

Comment: Hah, we decoded the same one `erase all rules`. It looked the same? Are you using [Code 128A](http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=80&style=197&type=C128A&width=200&height=50&xres=3&font=3), [Code 128B](http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=80&style=197&type=C128B&width=200&height=50&xres=3&font=3) or [Code 128C](http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=80&style=197&type=C128C&width=200&height=50&xres=3&font=3)? None of those look the same as the command barcode to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the 123Scan software does have this functionality... just not a very user friend program... somehow I didnt even see the button for this hidden in the top right.

Thanks for the help everyone